# Ionic page add common class for few selected pages

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5

I have few pages in my application that requires a certain styles to be applied to the page. Currently I have added the same css to the selector class.

**firstPage.scss**

```
firstPage{
  ion-content.content{
     background-color: $bgcolor;
  }
}
```

**nthPage.scss**

```
nthPage{
  ion-content.content{
    background-color: $bgcolor;
  }
}
```

If I don't want to use the same selector across all those pages is there any other method in angular or ionic which allows me to append a common class attribute along with the unique selector? Probably from the @Component or @IonicPage methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the perfect solution.

Angular didn't append a class to the selector when I tried something like this.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-my-page.common-page',
  templateUrl: 'post-ad-contact.html'
})
```

But it appended an attribute this way.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-my-page[common-page]',
  templateUrl: 'post-ad-contact.html'
})
```

Now I can append common styles to the common-page attribute instead of having to define for each page or extending each page with a common styles.

```
[common-page]{
  background-color: $mybg;
  .common-class{
    border: red;
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@extend` from sass.

You create the base style.

```
.basePage{
  background-color: $bgcolor;
}
```

Then extend it to your pages.

```
nthPage{
  ion-content.content{
    @extend .basePage;
  }
}
```

Do note though that your base class should be visible to the sass file where nthPage resides. So you might want to put your base class in a `base.scss` and import it to your `nthPage.scss`.

More info [here](https://css-tricks.com/the-extend-concept/).

Comment: I understand I can do that. My question is if there is a method to append a class to the page from ionic or angular. something like

    @Component({
       selector: 'page-one.common-selector',
       templateUrl: 'page-one.html',
    });

so that I don't have to repeat my selector names. Instead use a common selector.

Comment: I am still not quite sure of what you really want. The closest thing I can think of now is `styleUrls: []` from `@Component` decorator.

Comment: My problem was that I wanted to append some sort of common attribute the component selector along with the unique selector so I can add the common styles to the common selector without having to repeat my self. I found a solution. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

You could even go for:

```
    @Component({
           selector: 'app-nthpage',
           templateUrl: './nthpage.page.html',
           styleUrls: ['./nthpage.page.scss', '../firstpage/firstpage.page.scss'],
    })
```